# php button onclick to execute mysq - no display?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to php and mysql, currently working on using button onclick to execute mysql and return display on the local page. Code as following:

```
 <form method="GET" action="cake.php" id="form2">
  <button type="submit" form="form2">Cheese Cake</button>
</form>
```

Php code:

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

if (isset($_GET['form2'])) {

$query = $db->query("
    SELECT iname, qty FROM contain, ingredient
    WHERE cakeid IN ( SELECT cakeid FROM cake WHERE cakename = 'Cheese Cake') 
    AND contain.ingredid = ingredient.ingredid
    ");
    ?>

<?php
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    while ($r = $query->mysql_fetch_array()) {
            ?>
        <div class="result">
        <h4><?php echo $r->iname; ?></h4>
        </div>

        <?php

    }
}
}
```

There is no error to debug, but there is also no display on the page. The query is right and working on the Navicat database. The idea is to click the cake name button and get its ingredients. 
Many thanks for help

Comment: A quick debugging test would be in your cake.php script to use something like `print_r($_GET);` at the beginning to see what is coming through.

Answer (score 2):

change your button element like this

```
<button type="submit" name="form2">Cheese Cake</button>
```

And a suggestion,

don't use mysql use mysqli or pdo instead

Comment: many thanks!. it is the right answer. And also, I should use mysqli rather than mysql_num_rows. Thanks for debugging

Comment: @Joe - To clarify, it's not just `mysql_num_rows` specifically that needs to be changed. It's _all_ `mysql_*`-functions. I would also recommend PDO instead of MySQLi. That API is a bit easier and verbose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am sure gonna look into PDO in a sec.